# Vectorise comparison of integer arrays

Tags: c++, clang, vectorization

I want to compare for equality two integer arrays of unknown, but equal size. The compiler (clang++ 15.0.6 on Windows with flags `-O3 -march=native --std=c++20`) refuses to vectorise the comparison

```cpp
bool compare(int const* lhs, int const* const lhs_end, int const* rhs) {
    while(lhs != lhs_end) {
        if(*lhs != *rhs) {
            return false;
        }
        lhs += 1;
        rhs += 1;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Unrolling the loop manually does not result in the compiler vectorising the assembly either, yielding similar performance to the above

```cpp
bool compare(int const* lhs, int const* const lhs_end, int const* rhs) {
    while(lhs_end - lhs >= 4) {
        bool const cmp1 = lhs[0] != rhs[0];
        bool const cmp2 = lhs[1] != rhs[1];
        bool const cmp3 = lhs[2] != rhs[2];
        bool const cmp4 = lhs[3] != rhs[3];
        if(cmp1 || cmp2 || cmp3 || cmp4) {
            return false;
        }
        lhs += 4;
        rhs += 4;
    }

    while(lhs != lhs_end) {
        if(*lhs != *rhs) {
            return false;
        }
        lhs += 1;
        rhs += 1;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I wanted to hand-vectorise the code to improve the performance of the comparison, however, I have not found (or missed) vector instructions that perform (or could be used to perform) bitwise and/or on the contents of a vector register.

Are there any ways to vectorise or, in general, accelerate this comparison?

Comment: how to you determine / compare the performance?

Comment: I run the comparison code on the same input every time and time it @463035818_is_not_a_number

Comment: `std::memcmp` is pretty quick, have you seen if that meets your performance needs?

Comment: It actually runs somewhat slower than the first code snippet I posted @NathanOliver

Comment: If you rewrite it to compare the whole arrays no matter what, clang can vectorize it, perhaps you can play with it more? [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/zeGPhb4dd).

Comment: Is there a reason not to use `std::equal(std::execution::unseq, a.cbegin(), a.cend(), b.cbegin())`?

Comment: Is your function anyhow different from memcmp? How about copy https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/string/memcmp.c#L301 ?